# How to generate all evenly pairwise sampled bit-strings

Tags: bit-manipulation, combinations

I am trying to find small sets of bit-strings, ideally <= 2*N, where N is the number of bits, such that on any pair of bits, the combinations `'00', '01', '10', '11'` appear equal number of times.  On two bits this is obviously

```
00
01
10
11
```

while on 3 bits one can have either:

```
111
001
010
100
```

or the longer (not within 2N)

```
111
000
011
100
010
101
110
```

Finally on 4 bits I was able to get:

```
1111
0000
0101
1010
1001
0110
1100
0011
```

However, for the life of me I have yet to find a formula that actually yields these sets.  This problem seems to be something that someone else must have encountered before as well, and any pointers here would be most welcomed!

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_binary_sequence

Answer (score 0):

For four bits, the following is also a valid solution:

```
1111
0000
0101
1010
```

Each bit pair occurs 3x times across all bit strings.
In fact, this pattern generalizes nicely:

```
1111111...
0000001...
0101010...
1010101...
```

To see why this will always "balance out", look at each pair of adjacent columns. You have each bit pair occurring exactly once. Take for instance, the 3rd and 4th columns:

```
..11...
..00...
..01...
..10...
```

Same if you look at columns 2&3, 4&5, 5&6, so on.

Comment: Many thanks for taking a look.  However, if you notice in your four bit set, the 1st and 3rd bits have `11, 00, 11, 00` not the desired `11, 00, 10, 01`

Comment: @PaulNation Ah, my mistake. I thought you meant pairs of **adjacent** bits. Rereading your post, I see you make no such mention; I just inserted the adjacent restriction in my own head.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer but I tried to find some more examples using z3 in Python:

```py
import z3
N = 23
n = 24
assert (n % 4) == 0
v = [[z3.Bool(f'x_{i}_{j}') for j in range(N)] for i in range(n)]
solver = z3.Solver()
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        solver.add(z3.PbEq([(z3.And(v[k][i], v[k][j]), 1) for k in range(n)], n//4))
        solver.add(z3.PbEq([(z3.And(z3.Not(v[k][i]), v[k][j]), 1) for k in range(n)], n//4))
        solver.add(z3.PbEq([(z3.And(v[k][i], z3.Not(v[k][j])), 1) for k in range(n)], n//4))
        solver.add(z3.PbEq([(z3.And(z3.Not(v[k][i]), z3.Not(v[k][j])), 1) for k in range(n)], n//4))
if solver.check() == z3.sat:
    m = solver.model()
    xs = [''.join([('1' if m.evaluate(v[i][j]) else '0') for j in range(N)]) for i in range(n)]
    print('\n'.join(sorted(xs)))
else:
    print('no solution')
```

It seems that the pattern you observed holds in that for N = 4k+j, j < 4 you need 4(k+1) bitstrings. However, I wasn't really able to spot some pattern in the solutions, not even when imposing further constraints such as forcing one string to be all-zeroes. Here's an example for N = 23:

```
00001100100010110000011
00010010001101010000000
00101000010011011110100
00101001001100101001101
00110011111010001010011
00110101110101111101010
01000010101011101101110
01000110010100101110001
01011011010000010101111
01011101011111100010110
01101111100001000011000
01110100101110010111101
10000101111001000100101
10000111000111011011111
10010001000010100111000
10011110111000111011100
10101110011110000101010
10111010100101100110111
11001001101100011110010
11011000110111001001001
11100000011001110011011
11100011110110110000100
11110100000000001000110
11111111001011111100001
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that is problem is an example of a covering array: https://math.nist.gov/coveringarrays/coveringarray.html